# That is a bug in Kendo UI model dataannotation:the wrong tips in grid cell edit

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I define my viewmodel called `StockDataPoint` and view like this,in the viewmodel I limit that the color's length is 5.In the grid,if I edit the color such as input the string 'green1' which length is larger than 5,and the grid show `length no more than 5`,but when I input the 'green',it should be OK,but the grid still show `length no more than 5`.I have update the new version such as `kendo.all.min.js,jquery.min.js`，but it still not work.THe project is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmhrsidsnq27cku/ChartSeriesColorandGridCell.rar),and the picture is [here](https://www.hightail.com/download/elNJeUNITmFUWURIRHRVag)

**ViewModel:StockDataPoint**

```
public class StockDataPoint
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "length no more than 5")]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public double Close { get; set; }

    public int Volume { get; set; }

    public double Open { get; set; }

    public double High { get; set; }

    public double Low { get; set; }

    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

**View:grid to show and edit data**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ChartServerGrouping.Models.StockDataPoint>()
 .Name("DataGrid")
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
  .Columns(columns =>
    {
    columns.Bound(p => p.Close).Groupable(false).Title("Close").Width(120);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Color).Groupable(false).Title("Color").Width(120);
      columns.Command(command =>
        {
         command.Edit().UpdateText("Save");
         }).Width(160); })
     .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Type(GridSelectionType.Cell))
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                       .Ajax()
              .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Home"))
                .Update(read => read.Action("GetData", "Home"))
                  .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Date))
                  )
                 .AutoBind(true)
     .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true)))
```

Comment: What if you do the edit like this: _Green --> Green1 --> Blue_, does the message disappear?

Comment: Yes,it disappear.But if I input like this 'Green --> Green1----->Green',it do not disappear.

Comment: Ok, this is a bug related to the data validator, I've answered it in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22992362/1860561).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,in the official web it is a [bug](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui-error-on-grid-custom-validation).